# Объясните, как это работает? Стрелочные функции javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, framework7

Это пример из демки framework7

```
 <template>
  <div class="page" data-name="product">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-bg"></div>
      <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
        <div class="left">
          <a href="#" class="link back">
            <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
            <span class="if-not-md">Back</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">${currentProduct.title}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="block-title">About ${currentProduct.title}</div>
      <div class="block">
        ${currentProduct.description}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default (props, { $f7route, $store }) => {
    
    const products = $store.getters.products;
    const productId = $f7route.params.id;
    let currentProduct;
    products.value.forEach((product) => {
      if (product.id === productId) {
        currentProduct = product;
      }
    });

    return $render; //как это работает?
  };
</script>
```

Вопрос, как  дальше используется $render  и происходит отрисовка?

Comment: стоит посмотреть исходники `framework7`

Comment: Это никак не работает - $render is not defined

Comment: @Darth, это код внутри framework - он может добавлять свои специальные переменные при сборке ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: я думал, это свойство стрелочной функции. что в return можно непонятно что написать. Component is a function that receives props and context and should return render function.

Component render function should return Tagged template literal with component HTML content. - вот тут я не понял, выше функция в моем понимании инициализирует переменные шаблона, но я не понимаю, как она может возвращать сам шаблон

Comment: @Djames, непонятно что можно писать в любой функции.

Comment: @Grundy выше дополнил выдержкой из документации к фреймворк7, про непонятно что я имел ввиду, что незнаком с таким синтаксисом, думал, что в return указано название функции, что бы можно было, например, в стэке вызовов что-то понять. Только знакомлюсь с js

Comment: обрати внимание что данный файл собирается сборщиком и в процессе сборки в нем что угодно может происходить

Comment: Tagged template это https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B

Comment: только одна ссылка- в пользовательском js, шаблон в шапке - это всесь файл целиком, тоже предполагается, что пользовательский. Дальше собирается массив routes с этими шаблонами и все: var routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    url: './index.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/about/',
    url: './pages/about.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/form/',
    url: './pages/form.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/catalog/',
    componentUrl: './pages/catalog.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/product/:id/',
    componentUrl: './pages/product.html',
  }, ... Или под сборкой что-то другое имеете ввиду?

Comment: @darth спасибо, так становится понятнее

Comment: да, что-то другое. Твои исходники обрабатываются отдельно и меняются.

Comment: @Grundy, вы были правы. It is mandatory to have return $render in the end of the component function, as it will be replaced by parser with content of the <template> tag.